# guaranteed way to get instance of a class?

Tags: javascript, this

I come from C++, found out "this" only means execution context. Is there a guaranteed way to get self instance?

I ask this because I always try to get instance by "this" in javascript, but I have to do various ways to guarantee it by myself, such as ways described as follow:

```
MyClass.prototype.OnSomethingHappened = function () {
  // I want to get the reference to the instance of this class.
}
```

But this kind of function is often called like:

```
var bar = new MyClass();
foo.onclick = bar.OnSomethingHappened;
```

When onclick happend, OnSomethingHappened get called, but "this" does not mean the instance of bar.

There are some solution like:

```
var bar = new MyClass();
foo.onclick = function () {
  bar.OnSomethingHappened();
}
```

Yes, it works perfectly here.
But consider:

```
var bar = new MyClass();
MyClass.prototype.OnSomethingHappened = function () {
  // I want to get the reference to the instance of this class.
}
MyClass.prototype.IWantToBindSomething = function () {
  // sorry for using jquery in a pure javascript question
  $("div#someclass").bind("click", function () {
  bar.OnSomethingHappened();
  });  // I think this is a very very bad practice because it uses a global variable in a class, but I can't think of other workaround, since I have no guaranteed way of getting the instance.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the concept of a "class" really doesn't exist in JavaScript the way it does in C++.  There's no intrinsic relationship between a function and any particular object.  Functions are just values.

(Well there's no relationship other than the "casual" relationship when an object has a property that refers to a function.)

However, it's possible to force a particular value of `this` by wrapping a function in another function that uses `.call()` or `.apply()` to invoke the target function. You can do that with `.bind()` in newer browsers, or simply with an anonymous (or not-anonymous) wrapper.

*edit* — what's important to understand about `this` is that it's value is *completely* determined by the way a function is invoked, at each point of invocation. Thus, if you have an object:

```
var myObj = new Something();
```

and you want to use `myObj.handler` as an event handler (common situation) such that `this` in the event handler refers to the object, you simply need a wrapper:

```
$('whatever').click( function(ev) { myObj.handler(ev); } );
```

In that example, it's not necessary that "myObj" be a global variable:

```
function justAnExample() {
  var myObj = new Something();

  $('whatever').click( function(ev) { myObj.handler(ev); } );
}
```

In that you can clearly see that "myObj" is a local variable inside the "justAnExample" function. Because JavaScript has real closures, the invocation context of "justAnExample" is preserved after a call, and it's there for use by the anonymous wrapper function passed as the event handler to jQuery.

Comment: But that still need to call it with a global instance. Consider my last code case, is there a good way to do that? I just don't understand why "this" similar to C++ is not provided to js?

Comment: No, you don't need a global instance.  JavaScript is just a completely different language, with a significantly different execution model.